# How can I read first host name in jboss-cli

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm writing a jboss-cli script which manipulates the servers in a host.xml file, however I'm not able to retrieve the host name (the name has to be dynamic).

I am able to get a list of the current host names with the following

```
set host=`:read-children-names(child-type=host)`
```

but the value returned is a list, not a single item.

```
echo $host
["master"]
```

Is there a way to get the first host in the list? Or is there an alternative way to read the current host? (we're never expecting more than one)

Thanks if you can help!

EDIT: My workaround was to use the COMPUTERNAME environment variable (Wildfly is running on Windows), knowing that the Wildfly host name *should* always be the same as the computer name. (This customer's servers are all set up in this way). However, I would prefer to do this properly.

Comment: Do you want the first host name or the host name being used?

Comment: The host being used preferably... however, I know that in this particular case there will always only be one host, so either one is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to get the host name in use, you can use the `local-host-name` attribute.

```
set host=`:read-attribute(name=local-host-name)`
```

That produces something like:

```
[domain@embedded /] echo $host
primary
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I thought I looked for this everywhere, but  I didn't find it :-)